# in java,how to handle threads when creating dynamically

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created threads for each file.code is given below.

AList is an array list contains file name `{test1.txt,test2.txt,test3.txt}`

```
for(String str : AList){

  thread t = new Thread(new Filechange(str));
  t.start();

  }
```

Filechange class is given below.

```
public class C implements Runnable {

  private String tmp;


  public Filechange(String strg) {
   this.tmp = strg;
  }

  public void run() {

  system.out.println("File Name ::"+tmp);

  } t.sleep(1000);
   t.run();


  }
```

When running this code, always I am getting output `"File Name ::test3.txt"` .
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You made mistake while posting code. please correct it

Comment: Does that posted code compile? And where's your main method?

Comment: This cannot be your real code (it won't compile). Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a list of threads or something? I think that when you reassign the "thread t" all the time, you are overwriting the previous thread, thus, only the last thread is surviving. Do somthing like this:

```
List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(String str : AList){

  threadList.add(new Thread(new Filechange(str)));
  threadList.get(threadList.size()-1).start();

}
```

Comment: You can't "overwrite" a thread just by reassigning a variable. The Thread object remains until the thread completes.

Comment: I'd assign the newly created thread to a local variable instead of the `threadList.get...` call. It'll be much easier to read.